# Show that $cn= \left(\frac{n-2}{x} \right)^x \left( \frac{2}{1-x} \right)^{1-x}$ has a solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can we show that the following equation has a solution for $x \in [0,1]$
\begin{align}
cn= \left(\frac{n-2}{x} \right)^x  \left( \frac{2}{1-x} \right)^{1-x}
\end{align}
where $n>2$ and $c>\frac{1}{2}$.

I know find an exact solution is probably impossible, but can we show that the solution exists.

Comment: You also need $c < 1$. See my answer for details.

Comment: @martycohen  Thanks. I also have this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)
= \left(\frac{n-2}{x} \right)^x  \left( \frac{2}{1-x} \right)^{1-x}
= \frac{(n-2)^x}{x^x}  \frac{2^{1-x}}{(1-x)^{1-x}} 
= \frac{(n-2)^x2^{1-x}}{x^x(1-x)^{1-x}} 
$.

For $x \in [0, 1]$,
$\frac12 \le x^x(1-x)^{1-x}
\le 1
$
and
$x^x(1-x)^{1-x}$
is $1$ at $0$ and $1$,
and has its min of $\frac12$
at $x=\frac12$.

$(n-2)^x2^{1-x}
=2(n/2-1)^x
= 2 \text{ at } x=0,
= \sqrt{n/2-1} \text{ at } x=\frac12,
=n-2 \text{ at } x=1
$.

Therefore
$f(0) = 2$
and
$f(1) = n-2$,
so
$f(0)-cn
= 2-cn$
and
$f(1)-cn
= (1-c)n-2
$.

So,
if $cn \ge 2$
and
$(1-c)n \ge 2$,
there is a root in $[0, 1]$.